# Description of API: accountType row in POST HTTPS request for ClientLogin

Tags: google-docs-api

I can't uderstand one of three values for accountType row in POST request for ClientLogin. 
Can you help me, What means "HOSTED" value?

Description of ClientLogin POST Request: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps#Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hosted account is a user account that is part of the Google Apps service. The documentation page you linked defines those values.

Comment: OK, then "GOOGLE" value is part of the Google Accounts service?

Comment: A GOOGLE account is basically a gmail.com account